# Where do we draw the line with reference to treatment of non muslims?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation

> Hammam b. Munabbih reported:
>
> That is what Abu Huraira reported to us from the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) and he narrated (some) ahadith one of which is that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: I have been helped by terror (in the hearts of enemies) and **I have been given words which are concise but comprehensive in meaning**. ([Sahih Muslim 523f](https://sunnah.com/muslim:523f))

How can we understand this Prophetic statement? How can we determine what is valid or invalid meaning? If the Qur'an and ahadith are comprehensive in meaning then where do we draw the line?

I've seen many interpretations that people fall into confusion on which is true or false, exegesis or eisegesis, orthodoxy or heresy.

I need help.

Answer (score 1):

Quran endorses the statement of Prophet(ﷺ) in Surah Anfal verse 12. The context here is **enemies of Islam**. Those who are hostile towards Muslims.

> (Remember) when your Lord revealed to the angels, "Verily, I am with
> you, so keep firm those who have believed. **I will cast terror into the
> hearts of those who have disbelieved**, so strike them over the necks,
> and smite over all their fingers and toes." Quran 8:12

Now read this:

> Allâh does not forbid you to deal **justly and kindly** with those who
> fought not against you on account of religion nor drove you out of
> your homes. Verily, Allâh loves those who deal with equity. It is only
> as regards those who **fought against you on account of religion**, and
> have driven you out of your homes, and helped to drive you out, that
> Allâh forbids you to befriend them. And whosoever will befriend them,
> then such are the Zâlimûn (wrong-doers - those who disobey Allâh).
> Quran 60:8-9

**Where do we draw the line?**

We draw line where the companions of the Prophet(ﷺ) drew. We understand and implement the way they implemented.

> Al-Awza’i said: “Patiently restrict yourself upon the sunnah, **stop
> where the people (ie the companions) stopped**, say what they say and
> refrain from that which they refrained. Traverse upon the path of your
> Salaf al-Salih, for indeed **what was sufficient for them is sufficient
> for you.**” (Al-Shari’ah of al Ajurri, pg58)